# Quickreports with multiple pages

Tags: delphi, quickreports

Assuming that I have a Title, sub detail and footer. Both footer and title are static (won't change) while the sub detail is dynamic, basically drawing a table from a database.

How is it possible to make it load a specific amount of lines in the Sub-detail and creating as much pages as needed? Let's say I have 30 lines in my database table. and I want to limit 10 lines per page. that will make it 3 pages

Answer (score 0):

you could have a local variable keeping track of the number of time the detail before print event has been called. Once it hits 10 call NewPage()

Answer (score 0):

You can use a child band
Enter your text in the child band, and when the data is more than one page, place a portion of your data on the next pages.
You can have more than one child band.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).